# Javascript array filter with Date ascending order and remove duplicate

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

```
years = [ Date, Date, Date  ]

// This gets date ascending order but not sure how can i remove duplicate   
this.years.sort(function(a, b) {
  let dateA:any = new Date(a); 
  let dateB:any = new Date(b);
  return (dateA - dateB);
});
console.log( this.years );
```

How can remove duplicate date in this sort function, Or do I need to write separately? and Is this script standard?

Comment: There's no way `sort` can change the length of an array. You should use `filter`. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Comment: I just add a hint, the proposed solution in the linked answers may not work as-is, since they could just compare the references. For this reason, I advise you tu map with `.map(date => date.getTime())` or if you want to be that cool guy, you can use `date => +date`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to remove items while sorting as the sort function just move indexes. I would suggest you to get the unique elements first so the resulting array to sort is smaller and you don't sort elements that will be deleted.

Please, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44906207/1361335) to get the unique values:

```
const dates = [Date, Date, Date];
const uniqueDates = dates.filter((date, i, self) => 
  self.findIndex(d => d.getTime() === date.getTime()) === i
)
```

And after that:

```
const uniqueDatesSorted = uniqueDates.sort((a, b) => a -b)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: When I trying this, it didn't worked for `Date` values. It works for other types, but I couldn't get it to work with Date. If you can provide a working example it can be helpful.

Comment: You're right! I've updated the answer. Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, `sort` can't remove duplicates, so in my solution I removed the duplicates first with `map` and `filter` and then applied the sort.

```js
let myArray = [new Date(2019, 06, 28), new Date(2019, 07, 28), new Date(2019, 06, 28), new Date(2019, 07, 14), new Date(2019, 07, 01), new Date(2019, 07, 16), new Date(2019, 07, 14)]

let unique = myArray.map((date) => +date)
  .filter((date, i, array) => array.indexOf(date) === i)
  .map((time) => new Date(time));

unique.sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(unique)
```